# Saving a certain motion in iOS and comparing other motion to it

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I want to know if this is possible in iOS or not. I want to calibrate a motion. For example If someone moves the iPhone vertically from one point to another, I want the iPhone to save that motion and if someone repeats the same motion the phone would be able to predict it. Is that possible using core motion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though of course the notions "save" and "compare" are completely up to you. You can get the *data* and keep it, but there is no magic formula for deciding whether the data from a later gesture matches the saved data.